# Finding the first four consecutive red candles of each trading day

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to isolate a simple pattern for each trading day, just the first set of consecutive red candles.

```
strategy("fourRed", overlay=true)

var fourRedOccur = false

fourRedCandles = not fourRedOccur and (close[3] < open[3]) and (close[2] < open[2]) and (close[1] < open[1]) and (close < open)

if (fourRedCandles)
    fourRedOccur := true

plotshape(series=fourRedCandles, style=shape.xcross, color=white, location=location.belowbar)
```

So far, I can't seem to:

1) Isolate only the first occurrence
2) Make it so this only shows up once per day (do I need to introduce `time`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to define your base condition:

```
fourRedCandles = sum(close < open ? 1 : 0, 4) == 4
```

Comment: thanks, and would I need to introduce `time` to do ensure my backtest occurs for some range, or does tradingview automatically do that?

Comment: If you're talking about the constraint you mentioned to the effect that the condition only occur once per day, that's taken care of in the code snippet already linked to in your answer. If you are thinking of limiting the backtest to a range of the dates, that can be implemented with [How do I implement date range filtering in strategies?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-do-i-implement-date-range-filtering-in-strategies).